# RESTful one or many

Tags: architecture, rest, api, api-design, web-api

What's a good way to design a RESTful URL pattern to get one and many results by ID ?

**One** (Response: *single item*)

```
/invoices?id=a/b
```

**Many** (Response: *array of items*)

```
/invoices?id=a/b&id=bar
```

The above approach looks nice in theory but raises a couple of concerns

- What (JSON) should be returned if `id` is omitted, `{}`,  or `[]`
- What will a client with a List of IDs of size one get back, an array or a single item

Comment: Keep in mind URLs are not a query language. A URL should represent a resource (**U**niform **R**esource **L**ocator), not provide a way to construct undefined queries to some underlying database level. A resource might be a collection of invoices (eg `/invoices/yesterdays` returning all of yesterdays invoices). But this way lies madness if you try and let the client query some database layer via URLs. You should just have a DB query API then, not a REST API. What is the client trying to do when it asks for a list of IDs. Who is deciding what that list should be, the client or the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traditionally you would use:

- /invoices  - obtain a list of all invoices and
- /invoices/1234 - obtain invoice with id 1234

So to answer your first question, "What if the id is omitted?", you'd end up with the request for all invoices.

If you needed several invoices, you'd request them *one at a time* from the server or you'd request for all of them and filter them on your own.  There isn't really a RESTful way of retrieving several specific invoices, nor should there be in my humble opinion.  More than likely you're dealing with all invoices or you're dealing with a specific invoice.  If your program isn't structured this way, consider doing so as it falls in nicely with the RESTful approach.

If you wanted to say, show a partial list of invoices, then consider something like:

/invoices/page/5

Comment: Would you still recommend path parameters where an ID can contain characters such as `/` ?

Comment: Well ideally you shouldn't use characters like / or ? in your ids, but understandably you might not have a choice.  You can still do something like /invoices/a%2Fb to mean invoice with id "a/b".  In other words, if you decode these characters, you can still make them work with REST.

Comment: Or, you can simply abandon the RESTful approach for this particular need.  Many, many API's do not follow RESTful principles at all, or do so only loosely or when REST is appropriate (i.e. CRUD).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Good point.  When you hold a hammer, everything looks like a nail as they say.  It, of course, doesn't *have* to be RESTful if it doesn't fit the program.

Answer (score 1):

> What's a good way to design a RESTful URL pattern to get one and many results by ID ?

Remember, REST doesn't care what spelling you use for your identifiers.

Something like

```
# Single item
/67a6e008-7d99-41ae-b680-3a2c8b3375ad

# Multiple items
/b484b03e-7726-434d-bb25-1a5da0a7315a
```

is *fine*.

> What (JSON) should be returned if id is omitted

You should return the representation of the identified resource.

`/invoices` and `/invoices?id=a/b` are *different* resources; for instance, they get cached separately.

> What will a client with a List of IDs of size one get back, an array or a single item

The client gets back the representation of the resource they requested.  There's nothing in the spelling of the identifier that specifies what the representation is going to be; that's what [Content-Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5) is for.  In the case of [application/json](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), it's going to be a [JSON-text](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-2) of some flavor, but that doesn't distinguish between an `object` and an `array`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to request multiple items is to create a custom collection resource, then request (via a link in the response) a full-fat version of the collection.

e.g.

```
POST /invoice-collections
{
    "items" = [
        "/invoices/1",
        "/invoices/5",
        "/invoices/8",
        "/invoices/9"
    ]
}


201 Created
Location: /invoice-collections/99
Link: </invoice-collections/99?depth=full>;rel=http://johan.example/relations#full-depth

{
     "items" = [
        "/invoices/1",
        "/invoices/5",
        "/invoices/8",
        "/invoices/9"
     ]
}
```

Then you look for the `http://johan.example/relations#full-depth` link relation in the response and follow that.